# How do I pass a new key as an array with immer?

Tags: redux, react-redux, immer.js

Say I have some initial state like

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  updating: false,
  saving: false,
  data: {},
  error: null
};
```

And I want add to data as the result of an action but the data I want to add is going to be an array. How do I go about this?

I've tried

```
export default produce((draft, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_STATE.SUCCESS:
      draft.data.new_Array.push(action.payload);
      draft.loading = false;
      break;

    default:
  }
}, initialState);
```

but this errors.

If I start the initial state as

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  updating: false,
  saving: false,
  data: {
    newArray: []
  },
  error: null
};
```

any update to the state before I make the array key overwrites the initial state and removes the key. ie

```
export default produce((draft, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OTHER_UPDATE_STATE.SUCCESS:
      draft.data = payload.action;
      draft.loading = false;
      break;

    default:
  }
}, initialState);
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

There's one thing I noticed you'll run into trouble, `draft.data.new_Array.push(action.payload);`

Make sure you don't modify the existing data structure. The reason is that `redux` relies on the memory reference of an object, if the object reference doesn't change, it might fool the `redux` that nothing actually happened in the past.

In your case, i have a feeling that nothing will ever get triggered.

One way to modify the reference is to create an new object, ex.

```
  return [...data, newElementObject]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've realised it was another action that was blooterating the original nested array that was stopping this from working